# Conjecture of the general form of a power series

Tags: functions, special-functions

Relcently I met a power series([Source Link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9802035v1.pdf)-Eq(4.1)) of the type
$$
f(x)=1-x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{4}x^3-\frac{1}{8}x^4-\frac{35}{128}x^5-\frac{157}{1024}x^6+\cdots
$$
where $x$ is supposed to be a small value. I just wonder that if anyone is power enough to GUESS the general behavior of the function? Maybe one can conjecture that it has the form
$$
f(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{4^{n-1}}x^n.
$$
where $a_n's$ are some integers.

Comment: Of course, any power series has the given conjectured form; do you mean perhaps for integer $a_n$?

Comment: Yes, you get it. But in that case, $a_0=1/4$ should be omited.

Comment: It doesn't look like it appears in [Sloane's](http://oeis.org/).  Unless you give us some idea of where this comes it's unlikely we'll be of any help.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my original question where I have attached the source.

Comment: Mathematica's `FindGeneratingFunction` does not succeed either.